# Tooltips: Isn't opaque supposed to mean OPAQUE?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Isn't opaque supposed to mean ***opaque***??

In particular, I've been experimenting with tooltip boxes in ***HTML application*** coding.  So far I have appropriated the following CSS code:

```
/* Begin Tooltip Tomfoolery */
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 2px solid magenta;
}
.tooltiptext {
    color: magenta;  background-color: yellow;
    text-align: justify;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 .25in;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 200px;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip  {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 0;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext  {
    visibility: visible; filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    z-index: 1;
}
/* -End- Tooltip Tomfoolery */
```

My tooltip boxes come out okay, but when I hover my mouse over ***one*** tooltip label, the text from ***neighbouring*** tooltip labels keeps bleeding through the chosen label's tooltip text, sometimes making the requested tooltip all but illegible.  Text outside of tooltip labeling appears to be covered adequately.  I've formatted my tooltip label-text combinations as below:

```
 <span class="tooltip"><em>Tooltip LABEL</em
><span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip TEXT</span></span>
```

*exempli gratia:*

```
<!-- earlier text --><span
     class="tooltip"><em>Krigah!&nbsp; Tarzan Bundolo!</em><span
     class="tooltiptext" style="left: 75px"
           >Beware!&nbsp; The Albino Kills!
           (and he ain't swingin' from no
            consarned rubber BAND neither!)</span></span><!-- later text -->
```

(***Aside:***  I don't know if your system allows tags to be split before the closing angle, but mine seems not to complain—plus it *does* allow me to control my line lengths for better source-code legibility.)  I tried playing with opacity and other field properties, but I think I've pretty much run out of options.  Any help you can provide will be ***deeply*** appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your complete html. What you have posted so far works fine on my pc

Comment: I've elaborated in « http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513784/re-tooltips-isnt-opaque-supposed-to-mean-opaque »

Comment: Don't. Edit this question if you want to add more information.

Comment: i can't actually see what you describe. If i use the code of your second post its works fine for me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your source has only `filter:alpha()`, no `opacity`, so I'm wondering.

Comment: As I said in the other question, when I hover over one tooltip label, some of the other tooltip labels interfere with the tooltip text.  The code is intended as an HTML application, so you might have to dicker with the dimensions of the application display.  For some display widths, the issue is inconspicuous; but for others, the interference renders the tooltip text all but illegible.  I don't know if its the computer I'm using, the software, the usage of .HTA instead of .HTML, or neglecting to tithe, but there seems to be a kink in the opacity property from my end.

Comment: I believe it's Microsoft Edge (perhaps Explorer), but I intended the file for offline usage.

Comment: @SFDavis That is vital information which should go into the question, rather than as an afterthought in a comment.